# establish two connections via SMACK API from same machine

Tags: java, smack

I'm making a simple chat client using OpenFire 3.7.1 and SMACK 3.2.2 on a localhost. I wish to know if it is possible to establish 2 connection to the server from the same machine.

**Illustration**: I have made a working client for simple exchange of messages. I'll run two jar files of the client (containing a login prompt), I'll make two different logins for two different users.

Now I tried doing that, but got Stream:error which I know refers to connection too many times or 2 users or something like that. I don't know the exact details about that error. Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can even do this from the same application.  There are integration tests run from Smack that do this all the time.

You only have to make sure to log in with different JID's.